# Tech expo in switzerland

Tags: switzerland

We're travelling to Switzerland around late july and going back home around 7th of August. We're highly interested in technology - and was wondering if anyone had any recommendations regarding places to visit there? For instance something like CES in Las Vegas - though way smaller I assume.

Comment: Switzerland where?

Comment: Anywhere honestly - we're travelling around several countries so it doesn't matter where inside Switzerland

Comment: Eaxct dates matter here - exhibitions/trade fairs aren't permenant things, but very much in passing.

Comment: It's not really consumer-oriented and quite different from the CES (and of course as @CMaster already mentioned it's a one off event) but [ITU Telecom World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITU_Telecom_World) was actually organised many times in Geneva (which is where the ITU's headquarters are located) and it is *big*.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find most of the interesting major trade shows are held in nearby Germany.

However, mid-summer is **really** not a good time for trade shows- most of them wind up for the summer by the end of June and begin again in the fall.

Munich has Automatica this year (June 21 - 24, 2016). I don`t see anything in that period in Dusseldorf or Hannover.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of trade shows in Switzerland this year.

I do not know if it is extensive, but is seems to include a lot of topics; but nothing really in the summer.

http://www.eventseye.com/fairs/c1_trade-shows_switzerland.html